# Engine hang when training large data

Tags: predictionio

I encounter problem with als, similar product template, when training 400 000 records (around 200 MB). 
It stop at Stage 13 : =====================                                     [0 + 1] / 2

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the mini Spark server when you launch the command:

```
pio train
```

This mini server is limited in resources. You need to launch your own Spark cluster. It can be started on the same machine as your PredictionIO server. You need to start Spark standalone with these commands:

```
./PredictionIO/vendors/spark-1.5.1/sbin/start-master.sh --webui-port 8180
./PredictionIO/vendors/spark-1.5.1/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://localhost:7077 --webui-port 8181
```

Then you can train using that Spark instance with this command:

```
pio train -- --master spark://localhost:7077 --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 8G
```

If `spark://localhost:7077` is not accessible you can open the Webui with port 8180 to see the URL of the master (first line of the page). Use that URL to connect your slave and your train.

Comment: Dear @bodyjares, I am using a 8G RAM machine, does it work with --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 8G? If not, to which number of Gigabytes RAM I need to reduce? Thanks so much.

Comment: By default the Spark slave is configured with the machine RAM - 1G so you can try to launch it with 7G. If you are not sure of how Spark slave is configured you can validate the available resources by going to http://localhost:8180. From there you will see the available memory on your worker.